# How mockk is able to return object wrapped in Result when returnArguments

Tags: kotlin, generics, mockk

I am still learning kotlin, and I am curious how is it possible that mockk is able to return some object `T` wrapped in `Result<T>`. For better understanding let analyse below example:

We have such method definition

```
fun save(toSave : Entity): Result<Entity>
```

when we mock such method using `returnArguments` like it is done below:

```
every { mocked.save(any()) } returnsArgument 0
```

Then method returns `Result<Entity>`, but logic says that `Entity` should be returned.
Looking into declaration of `returnsArgument` there is casting to generic type which in our case is `Result<Entity>`, but when I tried to do it in plain I had casting exception.

I assume some magic happens inside, but what magic is responsible for such thing?
Would it be done with any wrapping object or it is specific only to `Result`?

Comment: The next release of MockK will fix some value class bugs, fingers crossed https://github.com/mockk/mockk/pull/849#issue-1311787502

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Result<T>` is a [value class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-classes.html) and `mockk` has a [value class support](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/blob/master/agent/jvm/src/main/kotlin/io/mockk/ValueClassSupport.kt).

After many internal steps `returnsArgument` will wrap the argument `n` with the specified value class and will return it.

> Would it be done with any wrapping object or it is specific only to Result?

All value classes are supported, not just `Result<T>`.

```kotlin
// supported 
@JvmInline
value class ValueWrapper<out T> (val something: Any?)

// not supported
class SomeWrapper<out T> (val something: Any?)
```

Hope it helps.